# Two integrals are equal; what can we say from that

Tags: integration

I am new here. This might be a really basic question but if

$\int p(x) dx = \int q(x) dx$

How are $p(x)$ and $q(x)$ most generally related?

Comment: Just to confirm, you're considering indefinite integrals here?  So do you mean that the sets of antiderivatives are equal?

Comment: Hi Michael, thanks for your reply. Yes, that is exactly what I was looking for. If this is very trivial, can you point me to some resource where I can learn about this?

Comment: Differentiate both terms. This gives $p(x)=q(x)$. Assuming for example $p$, $q$ continuous.

Comment: That $p(x)=q(x)$ is a consequence of the fundamental theorem of calculus, which can be found any standard Calculus I text.

Comment: @coudy The assumption that $p$ and $q$ are continuous is not really needed, only that they have indefinite integrals.

Comment: Thanks for the nice answer. A follow-up question: can we say $p(x)=q(x)$ if the limit of the integral is from -inf to +inf?

Answer (score 1):

This is pretty dull for indefinite integrals. If $I(x)=\int f(x) dx=\int g(x) dx$ then $\frac{dI}{dx}=f(x)=g(x)$. We also have $\int f(x)-g(x) dx=C.$ for some arbitrary constant.

This is not the case for definite integrals though.

Supposed $f(x)=\sin x, g(x)=\cos x$.

$f(x)\ne g(x)$ but $\int_0^{2\pi}f(x)dx=\int_0^{2\pi}g(x)dx=0. $